# Is it possible to access a shadowed top level function in Swift?

Tags: swift

I was trying to write an Int extension to clamp an Int to a specific range, like this:

```
extension Int {
  func clamp(left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
    return min(max(self, left), right)
  }
}
```

I was getting a compiler error and after a while I realised that `min` is being interpreted here as `Int.min`, which is a constant for the lowest `Int`.

I can reimplement this avoiding `min`/`max` but I'm curious: is there a way I can reference those from an `Int` extension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can prepend the module name, in this case `Swift`:

```
extension Int {
    func clamp(left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
        return Swift.min(Swift.max(self, left), right)
    }
}
```

And just for fun: You get the same result with

```
extension Int {
    func clamp(left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
        return (left ... right).clamp(self ... self).start
    }
}
```

using the `clamp()` method from `ClosedInterval`.

Comment: Thanks. `Swift.` was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function `myMin<T>(a: T, b: T)` that calls `min` and use that in your extension.