# Fix error in Swift simd library (and missing documentation?)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, simd

I downloaded Apple's "[DemoBot](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/DemoBots/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015179)" project to try and learn more about `GameplayKit`, but there is one error preventing it from compiling. It's in an extension which seems to use the `simd` library. I did some research about SIMD and I can tell this stuff is over my head as a novice. But I just want to get this code working so I can demo the project.

The error is caused by this line from the code below:

`let fractionOfComponent = max(0, min(1, componentInSegment))`

The error message is:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Also, where can I find documentation for the `simd` library? I searched [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate) but there seems to be nothing on the `simd` library. How can I learn how to use the API in that library without getting a Computer Science degree?

```
import CoreGraphics
import simd

// Omitting the other extensions here

// Extend `float2` to provide a convenience method for working with pathfinding graphs.
extension float2 {
    /// Calculates the nearest point to this point on a line from `pointA` to `pointB`.
    func nearestPointOnLineSegment(lineSegment: (startPoint: float2, endPoint: float2)) -> float2 {
        // A vector from this point to the line start.
        let vectorFromStartToLine = self - lineSegment.startPoint

        // The vector that represents the line segment.
        let lineSegmentVector = lineSegment.endPoint - lineSegment.startPoint

        // The length of the line squared.
        let lineLengthSquared = distance_squared(lineSegment.startPoint, lineSegment.endPoint)

        // The amount of the vector from this point that lies along the line.
        let projectionAlongSegment = dot(vectorFromStartToLine, lineSegmentVector)

        // Component of the vector from the point that lies along the line.
        let componentInSegment = projectionAlongSegment / lineLengthSquared

        // Clamps the component between [0 - 1].
        let fractionOfComponent = max(0, min(1, componentInSegment))

        return lineSegment.startPoint + lineSegmentVector * fractionOfComponent
    }
}
```

### UPDATE:

Thanks to giorashc's answer I was able to fix the error by replacing the problematic line with the following:

```
let componentMin = Swift.min(1, componentInSegment)
let fractionOfComponent = Swift.max(0, componentMin)
```

However, I'd still like to find a good documentation resource for Swift's `simd` library (particularly one that a novice can understand). If anyone knows about such a resource that would be terrific.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062034/is-it-possible-to-access-a-shadowed-top-level-function-in-swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`float2` already has a `min` method that takes no arguments. (There is an explanation for the methods when you choose to go to their definition in Xcode)

Try using `Swift.min` to explicitly call swift's implementation

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was able to fix the error by replacing the problematic line with the following:
`let componentMin = Swift.min(1, componentInSegment)`
`let fractionOfComponent = Swift.max(0, componentMin)`